# Guardar X numero datos en un arreglo

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax

Quiero guardar en un arreglo los datos de los inputs, y al presionar el `boton`

```
agregar
```

los ponga en un tabla y así `x` numero de datos que quiera agregar, una ves que ya tenga toda la lista que al presionar el `boton de Guardar datos` envie ese arreglo con todos los datos de la lista, utilizando `ajax, jQuery`, 
Espero me puedan ayudar

```js
var parametros=[];
                var parame=[];
var par=[];
$("#datos div input, #datos div input:checked, #datos div select").each(function(i,e){
 var value ="";
                     
    parametro = {    
  "ckpID" : $(this).val()
    };
 parametros.push(parametro);

 });

par.push(parametros)
console.log(par);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="datos">
         <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
           <label>Existe:</label><br>
           <input type="checkbox" checked="true">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
           <label>Nombre:</label><br>
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
           <select id="elemento" class="form-control requerido">
                  <option value="1">Dato 1</option>
                  <option value="2">Dato 2</option>
                  <option value="3">Dato 3</option>
                  <option value="4">Dato 4</option>
           </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
           <label>Cantidad:</label><br>
           <input type="number" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
           <label for="sol_esUnidad">Es nuevo:</label><br>
           <input type="checkbox" checked="true">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
           <label>Adquirido:</label><br>
           <input type="number" class="form-control">
          </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
           <label>Prestado:</label><br>
           <input type="checkbox" checked="true">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left btn-tabla-nuevo">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Agregar
           </button>
            
            
            <div class="form-group">
     <table id="datostabla" class="table"><thead><tr><th>Existe </th><th>Nombre</th><th>Cantidad</th><th>Es nuevo</th><th>Adquirio</th><th>Prestado</th></thead></table> 
    </div>
        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left btn-tabla-nuevo">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Guardar Datos
           </button>
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te da?

Comment: Pero no nos estás mostrando las funciones click de los botones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno creo que he hecho lo que requerías, solo queda faltando que termines la lógica de tu ajax en el lado del servidor.

Para llevar a cabo tu requerimiento podrías hacer algo como esto:

```js
var parametros = [];
var parametro = [];

$("#boton_agregar").click(function(){
    $("#datos div input, #datos div input:checked, #datos div select").each(function(index, elemento){

        var id = $(elemento).attr('id');
        var valor = $(elemento).val();

        parametro[id] = valor;

    });

    $("#datostabla tbody").append('<tr><td>'+ parametro.existe +'</td><td>'+ parametro.nombre +'</td><td>'+ parametro.cantidad +'</td><td>'+ parametro.nuevo +'</td><td>'+ parametro.adquirido +'</td><td>'+ parametro.prestado +'</td></tr>')

    $("#nombre").val('');
    $("#cantidad").val('');
    $("#adquirido").val('');
    $("#elemento").val(1);

    parametros.push(parametro);
    parametro = [];
});

$("#guardar_datos").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'aca-tu-url.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: parametros,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(respuesta){
            // Función a ejecutar si hay una repsuesta positiva del servidor
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group" id="datos">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label>Existe:</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="true" id="existe">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label>Nombre:</label><br>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre">

            <select class="form-control requerido" id="elemento">
                <option value="1">Dato 1</option>
                <option value="2">Dato 2</option>
                <option value="3">Dato 3</option>
                <option value="4">Dato 4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label>Cantidad:</label><br>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cantidad">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="sol_esUnidad">Es nuevo:</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="true" id="nuevo">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label>Adquirido:</label><br>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="adquirido">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label>Prestado:</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="true" id="prestado">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left btn-tabla-nuevo" id="boton_agregar">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Agregar
</button>
            
<div class="form-group">
    <table id="datostabla" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Existe </th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Es nuevo</th>
                <th>Adquirio</th>
                <th>Prestado</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
        
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left btn-tabla-nuevo" id="guardar_datos">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Guardar Datos
</button>
```

Te corregí varios errores que tenías en la estructura HTML en cuanto al cierre de etiquetas.